# Is there a built-in way to get each slice of a given length from a vector in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

E.g.:

```
(each-slice 3 [1 2 3 4 5])
; => [[1 2 3] [2 3 4] [3 4 5]]
```

It would not be hard to write it, but is there a built-in way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no way to do it in a single function call if you want the slices returned as vectors. In two calls, it's still impossible if you really want slices (as created by `subvec`); otherwise you could use

```
(mapv vec (partition 3 1 [1 2 3 4 5]))
```

to get new regular vectors. Without the `mapv vec`, you'd get a seq of seqs.

Comment: Marczyk is this a case where a macro could be written to look like one call?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Well, as the question says, it's not difficult to implement a function to do it, and of course you could write a macro instead to inline the code into the caller (although it really makes no sense here). There's no built-in way to do exactly *this* (partitioning into slices with a step of 1) though.

Comment: Thanks, and you are right. I function that does two passes does the same thing.

Comment: For the golfing fun: `(let [v [1 2 3 4 5]] (mapv #(subvec v % (+ % 3)) (range (- (count v) 2))))` returns a vector of slices.